# -O2 flag in Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, dalvik, android-ndk-r7

When i use "-O2" flag, the performance much improve in linux but when i goes to android it slow,i want to build my shared library in android ,i use -O2 flag, but the performance is very slow,

whether any other flag is available in android to increase performance.

Comment: ...get a better phone? optimize your code? really, if it's slow you may want to look at your code some more.

Comment: Have you compared performance between `-O0` and `-O2` on your Android device? Note that if you set `CFLAGS := -O2` this may not be enough; the **NDK** adds its own `-O2` or `-O0` depending on release/debug build.